# anyway to find out screen width with Css

Tags: css, media-queries

using media queries `@media (min-device-width:1024px)` if we give like this,it will check whether width is atleast 1024px or not.Is there any way that we can use the device-width in our css,in order to set the width of our application body to the device-width?
another way with Jquery i can do like this

```
$('body').css('width',screen.width)
```

Is there any way that we can set the width to current screen width using css without touching Js.?

Comment: I'm not sure if it fits your needs, but there's a length unit called *[viewport percentage length](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)* you can use it like `body { width: 100vw }` where `vw` refers to the width of the viewport.

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible using the Viewport units like:

```
vw (viewport width) and
vh (viewport height)
```

Just like percents u can give this a value in percentages.

100vw will give u a width of the full screen and 100vh will give u a height of the full screen.

one problem it can have is browser support.
To know more about this check
http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

there is no only css way to capt the screen width, or you use media queries or you can use js/jquery solution to detect dynamically the width of the device , you can also use `max-width` and `min-width` with certain device but this require media queries any way , here is the current available solutions :

## **Jquery** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    if($(window).width() < 1500)
      // your code 
    else
      // your code
    });

    </script>
```

## **css**

```
@media (min-width: 700px) { ... }

@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }

@media tv and (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries to set the CSS dynamically, example:

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .wrapper {

  }
}
```

Alternatively you can use JavaScript to detect screen size and change CSS accordingly, here an example:

```
screen.height

screen.width
```

Answer (score 0):

If you work in percentages `html, body {width: 100%}` always sets the container to the size of the screen. From there you can do anything you want.